# WPF datagrid write programmatically on new row?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid on wpf. I am populating datagrid with codebehind. I want to write progmatically a value to datagrid's new row's first column . For example I am making this in C# as this

```
private void dataGridView1_RowEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].IsNewRow == true)
   {
       dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value "myValue"
   }
}
```

It works great on C# but in wpf I have problem. How can make this on wpf. I don't see RowEnter event . Does anyone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the CanUserAddRows dependency property of DataGrid to true. Add a button, by clicking which you could add a new row.

See the following example:

Xaml:

```
   <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="DataGridTest" CanUserAddRows="True" ItemsSource="{Binding TestBinding}" Margin="0,50,0,0" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Line" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Test1}" Width="50"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Account" IsReadOnly="True"  Binding="{Binding Path=Test2}" Width="130"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <Button Content="Add new row" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
```

CS:

```
 /// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var data = new Test { Test1 = "Test1", Test2 = "Test2" };

        DataGridTest.Items.Add(data);
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public string Test1 { get; set; }
    public string Test2 { get; set; }
}
```

In case you do not want to add a button for a new row, a nice solution exists in this [MSDN blog](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/46463fc9-fda6-4bf0-80f6-cd1e66f45690/)